# Controlling shown y-axis labels?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

So I am using the Charts framework (formerly ios-charts) for a couple of charts.

One of them in a bar chart where the y-axis is duration in seconds - that I then convert into readable minute:second notation with a formatter.

But the selected interval of labels bugs me a little. I would like to control them so they are only shown at intervals that makes sense for this - like say every half or full minute. But I can't seem to find a way to do that for that axis. Only the x-axis seems to have options for that?

So am I missing something here? Or it is not in the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops. Never mind. I found the 'granularity' property on the axis right after asking. And it seems to do what I need.